# How to use cache manager in MVC Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to activate second-level caching in EF Core that will cache the query result until the next time, instead of the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my CacheManager class

```
public class CacheManagerAdapter : ICacheService
    {
        private readonly YYYApi _api;
        private ICacheManager<object> _cacheManager;
        private static readonly string _cacheName;

        static CacheManagerAdapter()
        {
            _cacheName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cacheName"] ?? "CancelBookingCache";
        }

        public CacheManagerAdapter(IOptions<YYYApi> options)
        {
            _api = options.Value;

            _cacheManager = CacheFactory.Build("cacheName", settings => settings
                .WithUpdateMode(CacheUpdateMode.Up)
                .WithRedisCacheHandle("redisCache")
                .And.WithRedisConfiguration("redisCache", _api.cacheHost)
                .WithJsonSerializer()
                );
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            _cacheManager.ClearRegion(_cacheName);
        }

        public bool Contains(string key)
        {
            return _cacheManager.GetCacheItem(key, _cacheName) == null;
        }

        public object Get(string key)
        {
            try
            {
                return _cacheManager.GetCacheItem(key, _cacheName).Value;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }

        }

        public T Get<T>(string key, Func<T> getItemCallback) where T : class
        {
            return _cacheManager.Get<T>(key, _cacheName);
        }

        public void Invalidate(Regex pattern)
        {

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Invalidate(string key)
        {
            _cacheManager.Remove(key, _cacheName);
        }

        public bool IsSet(string key)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Set(string key, object data, int cacheTime)
        {
            try
            {
                _cacheManager.AddOrUpdate(key, _cacheName, data, x => data);
                if (cacheTime > 0)
                {
                    _cacheManager.Expire(key, _cacheName, ExpirationMode.Absolute, new TimeSpan(0, cacheTime, 0));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

the interface

```
public interface ICacheService
{
    void Clear();
    bool Contains(string key);
    T Get<T>(string key, Func<T> getItemCallback) where T : class;
    object Get(string key);
    void Invalidate(string key);
    void Invalidate(Regex pattern);
    bool IsSet(string key);
    void Set(string key, object data, int cacheTime);
}
```

So this is startup injection etc.

```
services.AddSingleton<ICacheService, CacheManagerAdapter>();

            services.AddSingleton<IMMMAdapterService>(new MMMAdapterService(
                XXX: new XXXController(
                    services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IOptions<YYYApi>>(),
                    _XXXLogger,
                    _diagnosticContext,
                    new CacheManagerAdapter(services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IOptions<YYYApi>>())
                    ), _XXXLogger, _diagnosticContext));
            services.AddSoapExceptionTransformer((ex) => ex.Message);
```

At the end, injection to controller

```
private readonly YYYApi _api;
readonly ILogger<XXXController> _logger;
readonly IDiagnosticContext _diagnosticContext;
readonly ICacheService _cache;

public XXXController(IOptions<YYYApi> options, ILogger<XXXController> logger, IDiagnosticContext diagnosticContext, ICacheService cache)
    : base(options, logger)
{
    _api = options.Value;
    _logger = logger;
    _diagnosticContext = diagnosticContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(diagnosticContext));
    _cache = cache;
}
```

Comment: Done, thansk for answer

Comment: wellcome my friend if you have challenging with other features write me we can got the way

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your project. You can cache data in multiple ways:

- Implement cache in repository pattern
- Write your own cache manager in separate class
- Use Redis like systems for caching
- Response caching in ASP.NET Core: [Details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-2.2)